# inbound and outband JMS queue mule class cast

Tags: jms, mule

I have got simple setup of mule. Reading from JMS queue processing message and in case of exception sending to DLQ. With Mule 3.3.0 and HornetQ 2.3.0.BETA1. I am getting following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mule.transport.jms.ReusableTopicSessionWrapper cannot be cast to javax.jms.QueueSession
    at org.mule.transport.jms.Jms102bSupport.createDestination(Jms102bSupport.java:231)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.Jms11Support.createDestination(Jms11Support.java:142)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsMessageDispatcher.dispatchMessage(JmsMessageDispatcher.java:163)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsMessageDispatcher.doDispatch(JmsMessageDispatcher.java:81)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher.process(AbstractMessageDispatcher.java:99)
    ... 113 more
```

My setup:

```
    <jms:connector name="connector.jms" maxRedelivery="10"  doc:name="JMS"

        jndiInitialFactory="org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory"
        jndiProviderUrl="jnp://localhost:1099"
        connectionFactoryJndiName="ConnectionFactory"
        createMultipleTransactedReceivers="true"
        numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="100"
        acknowledgementMode="AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE">
    <reconnect-forever frequency="5000"/>       
</jms:connector>
<flow name="jmsListenerFlow1" doc:name="jmsListenerFlow1">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="adsLogQueue" connector-ref="connector.jms" doc:name="JMS">
        <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <component >
        <spring-object bean="logSaver"/>
    </component>
    <catch-exception-strategy>
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="DLQ"> <!-- [2] -->
            <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" />
        </jms:outbound-endpoint>            
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Can it be bug in Mule itself ? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I removed the hornetq tag as I don't see anything related to hornetq on the question. Just mule. Although hornetq is being used it's not part of the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `specification="1.1"` on the `jms:connector`.

Comment: Thanks I have just found it as well :)